# Get Friday for the given week number in C#

Tags: c#

i need to find the date of friday for the given week number of the year
for ex(week 37).

(the first friday of the 2011 is the friday that is in the week of Jan 1st.
 in this case the first friday is dec 31st 2010.
)

Comment: That's a nice goal. What's the question?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: "How to do so" ?

Comment: As explained above first friday is the dec 31st 2010.
        i need to find the date of friday of the 37th week

Comment: find first friday of the year using this function. public static DateTime FirstFirdayOfYear()
        {
            var yearStart = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
            if (yearStart.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday)
            {
                while (yearStart.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday)
                {
                    yearStart = yearStart.AddDays(-1);
                }
                return yearStart;
            }
            else
            {
                return yearStart;
            }

        }

Comment: @srikanth, again, that's a nice goal. You need to find it. So *find it.* What part of the problem is stopping you? For example, algorithmically, it's not too difficult in a naive approach. Find first Friday -> Add *n - 1* number of weeks -> return *nth* Friday. Implement that. Post where you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime.Parse("12/31/2010").AddDays(36 * 7);
```

EDIT: I added a few more things, you may want a bit more, here I'm generating a list of dates, and you can then use LINQ to get what you want easily.

```
    public void DateThing()
    {
        List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();
        DateTime start = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2010");

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            dateList.Add(start.AddDays(i));
        }

        var dateYouWant = GetDayOfWeekForGivenYear(DayOfWeek.Friday, 37, 2011, dateList);
    }

    private DateTime GetDayOfWeekForGivenYear(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, int weekNum, int year, List<DateTime> dateList)
    {
        var days = dateList.Where(w => w.Year == year  && w.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek);
        var day = days.FirstOrDefault(w => w.DayOfYear >= (weekNum - 1) * 7);

        if (weekNum == 1)
        {
            return day.DayOfYear > (int)day.DayOfWeek ? day.AddDays(-7) : day;
        }
        else if (weekNum == 53 && day == default(DateTime))
        {
            return days.Last(w => w.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek).AddDays(7);
        }

        return day;
    }
```

Comment: This works fine if you want a date that falls within the next three years. It won't work past that .. or if the date is in the past. It also seems quite inefficient to generate a long list of dates each time you want to pick just one. Dates are easily calculated with just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this ...

```
    var year = 2011;
    var week = 37;
    var date = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);

    while (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday) date.AddDays(1); 

    date = date.AddDays(7 * (week - 1));
```

This makes the assumption that week 1 of a year is the week of the first Friday. This may not always be the case ... you may want the first week of the year to be the first full week .. or the first part week ... adjust as required. Hope this helps :)